# Woocommerce_Created_Customer hook send email with extra fields not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When using the **woocommerce_created_customer** hook to send a custom email with the users username, password and email it all works.

But if I try to add the following fields: first name, last name and company name. It won't show the fields in the receiving email. And I can't find out what's wrong!

So basically what I need is: username, password, email, first name, last name, phone number and the company name.

**This is what I got at the moment, but is only showing the username, password, email and customer/user ID.**

```
    // send Customer details
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'create_cd_account', 10, 3 );

function create_cd_account( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated ) {

// Get the New Customer's details
$username   = $new_customer_data['user_login'];
$password   = $new_customer_data['user_pass'];
$email      = $new_customer_data['user_email'];
$role       = $new_customer_data['role'];


// Get an instance of the WC_Customer Object
$user = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );

// Get the first name and the last name from WP_User Object 
$first_name = $user->first_name;
$last_name  = $user->last_name;
$phone      = $user->billing_phone;
$company    = $user->billing_company;


// Continue and send the information
// Testing sending email
$to = 'myaddress@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Test email - does it work?';

$message = "Hello, {$first_name}\n\n";
$message .= "Here are your login details:\n\n";
$message .= "Your company is: {$company}\n\n";
$message .= "Your name is: {$first_name . ' ' . $last_name}\n\n";
$message .= "Your customer/user ID is: {$user->ID}\n\n";
$message .= "test extra user ID: {$customer_id}\n\n";
$message .= "Your username is: {$username}\n\n";    
$message .= "Your password is: {$password}\n\n";
$message .= "Your email is: {$email}\n\n";
$message .= "Your role is: {$role}\n\n";
$message .= "Your phone number is: {$phone}\n\n";

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', $from_func = function ( $from_email ) { return 'info@mydomain.com'; } );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', $from_name_func = function ( $from_name ) { return 'My Wordpress Website'; } );

// send email
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from', $from_func );
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', $from_name_func );
}
```

**I also tried the following (no luck) using:**

```
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $customer_id );
```

and

```
$customer = get_userdata($customer_id);
```

**I hope someone can tell me where it's going wrong? And how to make it work.**

Answer (score 0):

your code helped me but i think my code can help you. I only needed firstname and lastname so i used `$_POST['first_name']` like this. I think this works for you too. Just replace the firstname with the name of the inputs